# Reading Dates from PostgreSQL in Laravel

Tags: laravel, datetime, laravel-5.1, php-carbon

I'm trying to create an object in Laravel and when I set the date I get an error.

**Code**

```
<?php

$result = pg_query($this->conn, "SELECT * FROM cliente");

if (!$result) {
    $this->message('Error to query cliente');
    exit;
}

while ($row = pg_fetch_row($result)) {
    if ($row[7] == null) {
        $cliente->fecha_nacimiento = null;
    } else {
        $fechaString = (string)$row[7];
        $fecha = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', trim($fechaString));
        $cliente->fecha_nacimiento = $fecha;
    }
}
```

**Error**

> [ErrorException]
>   DateTime::createFromFormat() expects parameter 2 to be string, object
>   given

If I use Carbon:

```
$fecha = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', trim($fechaString));
```

Getting:

> [InvalidArgumentException]                   The separation symbol
>   could not be found   Unexpected data found. Trailing data

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If I print  $row[7] the output is 1963-10-05

Comment: Is there a reason why you are not using models and/or the Eloquent/Query Builder?

Comment: I dont want  to create a model because thats code is part of a process to migrate data from other database.

Comment: @Matiasgraña not good.. seriously.. have to use at least Query Builder for safe guarding sql injection, and more readable code.. although i know its difficult to migrate weird and long queries into either Eloquent or Query Builder.